# Version → (many to many) → Function → (belongs to) → Category

Tags: php, laravel

I have following table layouts:

```
functions:
- id
- name
- category_id

categories:
- id
- name

versions:
- id
- name

function_version
- function_id
- version_id
```

I would like to call the following relationships

From version model
$version->categories

From category model
$category->versions

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's no indication that you've actually tried anything here. From where I'm standing you're just asking someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 2):

See this lib:
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Examples in README.md.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As laravel explain [Laravel Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) in their docs, for many to many you can use this code

```
public function 'function name'()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App Model Name::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

1. From version model:

   ```
   $version = Version::with('functions' => function($query) {
       $query->withCount('category');
   })->firstOrFail();
   return $version->functions->category_count;
   ```
2. From category model:

   ```
   $category = Category::with('functions' => functions($query) {
       $query->withCount('versions');
   })->firstOrFail();
   return $category->functions->versions_count;
   ```

for above code you have below relationship in particular model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function functions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Function::class);
    }
}

class Function extends Model
{
    public function Category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function versions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Version::class);
    }
}

class Version extends Model
{
    public function functions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Function::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I get directly how many versions are in one category or how many categories are in one version? I don't want to get Functions. Like has many through.

Comment: please check updated answer